# Extracting number from a string including special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a decimal number from a string, but the problem is, suppose if I have the string `Was $12.00`, the following function is able to extract `12.00`, but if the string is `$12.00` (including the dollar sign), it's giving me an output of `null`.

I have this function:

```js
var OverriddenValue = process.argv[2];
let NumberExtracted;

if (OverriddenValue == 'null') {
  NumberExtracted = '';
}

ExtractNumber(OverriddenValue,NumberExtracted);

function ExtractNumber(OverriddenValue,NumberExtracted) {
  NumberExtracted = OverriddenValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
  // NumberExtracted = OverriddenValue.replace(/\D/g, "");
  console.log("NumberExtracted",NumberExtracted)
  return NumberExtracted;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `"$12.00".replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "")` produces `12.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ? (no need for a `+`)

```js
const ExtractNumber = str => str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')

console.log( ExtractNumber( 'Was $12.00' ));
console.log( ExtractNumber( '$12.00' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the currency value using the following expression: `/[\d]+\.[\d]+/g`

```js
const extractCurrencyValue = text =>
  (([ result ]) => result ? parseFloat(result) : undefined)
  (text.match(/[\d]+\.[\d]+/g) || []);

const testCases = ['Was $12.00', '$12.00', 'foo']; // 12.00, 12.00, undefined

testCases.forEach(testCase =>
  console.log(extractCurrencyValue(testCase)?.toFixed(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your regex, other than an unnecessary escape before the dot `\.` in the character class which does not affect the results (a dot does not act as the match-any metacharacter when in a character class and does not need to be escaped).

You say *"if the string is $12.00, it's giving the output null"* but that is impossible: `anyString.replace(/anyRegex/g, "")` *can **not*** produce `null` — but you're not showing example inputs and outputs.

I would have commented further, not "answered", but could not demonstrate the following in a comment. These produce the same results, and both work. Neither produces `null` when given the string `"$12.00"`.

```js
/*
var OverriddenValue = process.argv[2];
let NumberExtracted;

if (OverriddenValue == 'null') {
  NumberExtracted = '';
}
*/

// Some test data
const test1 = "12.00";
const test2 = "Was 12.00";
const test3 = "$12.00";
const test4 = "Was $12.00 dollars";

// Using your original function
console.log("Original function tests:");
let result1 = ExtractNumber(test1);
let result2 = ExtractNumber(test2);
let result3 = ExtractNumber(test3);
let result4 = ExtractNumber(test4);

console.log(`test1: "${test1}" result: "${result1}"`);
console.log(`test2: "${test2}" result: "${result2}"`);
console.log(`test3: "${test3}" result: "${result3}"`);
console.log(`test4: "${test4}" result: "${result4}"`);

// Using a slimmed down version of the function
console.log("Slim function tests:");
result1 = getNumber(test1);
result2 = getNumber(test2);
result3 = getNumber(test3);
result4 = getNumber(test4);

console.log(`test1: "${test1}" result: "${result1}"`);
console.log(`test2: "${test2}" result: "${result2}"`);
console.log(`test3: "${test3}" result: "${result3}"`);
console.log(`test4: "${test4}" result: "${result4}"`);


function ExtractNumber(OverriddenValue,NumberExtracted) {
  NumberExtracted = OverriddenValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
  // NumberExtracted = OverriddenValue.replace(/\D/g, "");
  console.log("NumberExtracted",NumberExtracted)
  return NumberExtracted;
}

// Slimmed down
function getNumber(fromString) {
  return fromString.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the only 2 special chars you're having issues with are the `.` and the `$`, try this RegEx:

`/\$?\d\.?/g`

That'll handle any decimal number(s) including a `.`, with or without a `$` in it. If you want to exclude matches with a `$` just remove this from the RegEx:

`\$?`

https://regex101.com/r/JWTUuT/2